# What's The Big(O) Complexity of this loop?

Tags: python, big-o

```
def cups (a,b):
    i=0
    j=0
    done = False
    while not done:
        if a[i]==b[j] :
            print("A[" + str(i) + "] with B[" + str(j) + "]")
            i += 1
            j = 0
        if i == len(a):
            i=0
            done = True
        if a[i] != b[j] :
            j += 1
```

I'm trying to compare two lists and print the indices of two values that are the same in the two lists

I'm curious whether the complexity is O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: `while ...` **is** a loop, and it runs len(a) times.

Comment: so it's O(n) ? or should we say O(1) since it is while not False?

Comment: One can try timing the code with varying lengths of a and b.

Comment: It's O(len(a)), as it runs len(a) times.

Comment: Since you have a `while` loop and also `i += 1`, it cannot be `O(1)`.

Comment: @Thierry it's higher than just O(len(a)) if the last element of a doesn't match any elements of b

Comment: Though, there needs to be a check for `j >= len(b)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Right, I hadn't really looked at the content of the loop...

Comment: hmm .. are you assuming that the list is sorted? if so, if the values are not equal then you need to advance the index of the list with the smaller value, which you are not doing.

Comment: This code seems pretty broken. Are you sure this works the way you want it to? 
Can you state your assumptions about the data you're getting?

Comment: @CharbelAllawi As I suspected, if your code is producing correct results on unsorted lists, it is running in O(n**2) time. See my answer below for fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your code might not be working the way you want it to, but this question seems to be more about algorithmic complexity and less about your particular implementation, so I'll focus on that.

In general, two *sorted* lists can be compared in the way you describe in linear time by advancing pointers. We can use two streets of numbered houses as a concrete example: if you and I want to find out what house numbers are duplicated on Main Street and Elm street, we can do the following:

1. you start at the bottom of Main Street, I start at the bottom of Elm Street.
2. we each report the number that we see
3. if the numbers match, we record that number
4. if not, one of us is seeing a number that is lower than the other. That one walks up the street until they find a number which is equal to or greater than the last one reported by the other and repeat from step 3

In this case, neither of us ever goes back to the bottom of the street.

However, if the lists are not sorted, then we have to use a different approach. Assuming that Main Street and Elm street are numbered in random order, we have to do the following:

1. I start at the bottom of Elm Street.
2. I report the number that I see.
3. you start at the bottom of Main street and walk up until you find a house that has that number, or until you reach the end of Main. If you find a match, we record it.
4. I advance to the next house and we repeat from step 3.

This is an O(n**2) algorithm, as you can see (you walk up Main St. once for each house on Elm, if there are n houses on each street then we're looking at n * n operations)

This is the state you're in - the problem you're stating cannot be solved in O(n)

However, I will point out that sorting a list is an O(n log n) operation, which would allow you to reduce the problem to the linear case, for a final complexity of O(n log n)

Comment: I'm Trying To Approach The Output At O(n) or (O(1) if it is somehow possible) –

Comment: It is not possible unless you know that the lists are initially in sorted order. If you do not have this guarantee, then the best you can do is O(n log n), by sorting both lists and then using the algorithm for sorted lists.

Comment: If both lists are sorted, then O(n) is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You're scanning all elements of at least one list, so it cannot be constant

The best case, since you're setting `j=0`, is when all elements of `a` equal the first element of `b`, therefore making all elements of `a` the same, and this is linear time, but big-O does not measure best case

In the worst case, you're scanning all elements of both lists. For each non-equal element, you're scanning all of `b` until matched; and when you find a match, you're resetting `j` back to the start of `b`, so really it would be O(N*M), and for equal length lists, this is O(N^2)

Note: the more generic algorithm for this is this

```
for a_elem, i in enumerate(a):
    for b_elem, j in enumerate(b, start=i)
        if a_elem == b_elem:
            print(f"a[{i}] with b[{j}]")
```

Comment: Thank You For The Reply, I'm Still Curious Is There Anyway To Achieve it At O(1) , Assuming That The Lists A And B Have The Same Length

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: Since the list s are not sorted, an O(N) algorithm is not possible.

Comment: Here's a question that can be answered with an O(1) algorithm: "Given two *sorted* lists of integers, decide if there could be *any indexes* where the two lists have the same element." (Solution: look at the first and last elements of both lists, return True if ranges overlap, False otherwise; solution does not change with length `N` of lists).

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm Trying To Approach The Output At O(n) or (O(1) if it is somehow possible)

Comment: @Charbel, Again, constant time is not possible if you want to find every matching index, even if you had just one list and one number to compare. You also cannot do near linear time without assumptions (sorted data) or specific inputs (all elements are equal)

Comment: @Alex Thanks, but I don't see how that's relevant to my answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry to interrupt you , I'm still new here and I could not delete the post since it has valuable answers , is there any way to unlink it or force delete it , the question content is related to  my university and I don't want to go into troubles :(

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is a tangent. I got the impression OP was having trouble understanding what O(1) actually meant, and hoped an example could complement your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside any bugs you have in the code - and concentrating on the runtime complexity question:

`O(1)` means the code is running at a constant time regardless of the size of the input, and clearly here it is not the case since different sizes of a and b will result in different numbers of loop iterations.
In your case your while loop can iterate at most len(a) * len(b) times (roughly)
So you can say that the code has a run time complexity of the order of `O(n)`, where `n=len(a)*len(b)`

Comment: Unless I missed something, I don't think the lengths would be multiplied

Comment: Given this example: a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] and b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1] you will iterate over all the items in b for each element you are comparing in a. Therefore your loop will perform length(b)*length(a) iterations